# How to uppercase letters after certain characters?

Tags: php, string

How can I modify a string in the following ways?

- first character uppercase
- first character after the hyphen uppercase
- first character after the slash uppercase

Here are some examples:

```
$a = 'foo-bar';
echo $a; // FooBar
$a = 'my-class-name';
echo $a; // MyClassName
$a = 'my-directory/my-class-name';
echo $a; // MyDirectory/MyClassName
$a = 'my-directory/my/sub/directory/my-class-name';
echo $a; // MyDirectory/My/Sub/Directory/MyClassName
```

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: [Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php).

Comment: Why is this being closed as too broad? How is it not "a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For something like this you can use [ucwords()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) and [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) e.g.

```
echo str_replace('-', '', ucwords($a, '-\/'));
```

The `'-\/'` basically means it will treat `-` and `/` as delimiters so it knows what to class as a new word.

Hope this helps!

Comment: :Ross Wilson - Thank you very much ;)